# Meteor selecting packages loop

Tags: javascript, meteor, package

I have an issue with Meteor. Initially project was developed on meteor 1.2.1 after that we made an update to 1.4 and figure out that some packages are not supported in 1.4 so we decided to make a downgrade to 1.2.1.

What I have tried is creating a new project with 1.2.1 release and porting the project files into new project but when I try to load the project it gets stuck in selecting package versions and remained there for a long time I have waited for already for 30 minutes and still no result.

Also I tried just to run Meteor  update --release 1.2.1 the same result.

Comment: Did you try bumping the versions of the unsupported packages? Also, you may need to fix versions of packages jnstalled. Alternatively, wait till meteor does it thing.

Comment: @Ankit the thing is that it gets stuck and even the "|" that indicates that is working is stoped and doesn't flip, also the CPU goes 90% .

Comment: Okay. I got stuck into a similar situation with 1.3, I left it running overnight and it worked fine. If you can retrieve previous version of .meteor/versions file, and replace the current one.